# Combine 2 CharFields to form an attribute

Tags: django, django-models

I want combine the `first_name` and `last_name` fields to create a `full_name` field. Which will then be used to create the slug.

I get `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` with this code.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    full_name = self.first_name + " " + self.last_name 
    slug = AutoSlugField(null=True, default=None, unique=True, populate_from='full_name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a property in the class. This returns slug property as

```
>>> e.slug
'sandesh-daundkar'
```

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(null=True, default=None, unique=True, populate_from='full_name')

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Class methods can be soultion

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(null=True, default=None, unique=True, populate_from='full_name')

    @property
    def last_name(self):
        full_name = self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
        return full_name
```